# How to build a sturdy wooden riser for a mini-fridge

Tags: wood, refrigerator, support

all, I want to raise an under-counter mini-fridge (90 pounds loaded) from the floor. It measures 18"w x 18.5d" x 28"h. It's for an elderly woman who can't bend over to use anything below the upper freezer door. I'm thinking of attaching a 22" 3/4 plywood square onto 10" legs cut from a 4x4 post. I plan to screw coasters onto the plywood top for the fridge legs to sit in so the fridge won't slip off the box when the door is opened.
Questions:
#1. Will the materials in mind support 100 lbs?
#2. Can it be a just a low table or would it have to be a box?
#3. How can I keep the fridge from toppling off the riser if the fridge is bumped or the fridge door is roughly handled? I can't attach it to the wall in any way. I'm thinking running a house-mover's strap (the kind with a ratcheting clamp) around it and through slots cut into the plywood top), but that would be hard to manage if the support is a box. And there must be a more attractive option!
Thank you

Comment: Small kitchen cabinets exist, and are well built, and can be had used if cost is a factor. Getting to be a long time in the past, but the other handy and very sturdy common thing in this size range is a typewriter table (steel office furniture) which should be inexpensive if you can find one *e.g.* at Habitat Restore (where you might also find a cabinet,) Goodwill, or Salvation army or other "thrift"/secondhand stores.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fridge with legs that you are going to set atop a table with legs.

**Instead, why not give the fridge longer legs?**

Maybe you can make legs from your 4x4s then firmly attached the fridge legs to them?  Or remove the fridge legs and use a double sided screw / bolt to screw into the wood and bolt in the holes for the fridge legs.

[image: bolt and screw]

As regards tipping over, you can put cinder blocks on the floor underneath in front of the back legs and attach the legs to the blocks.  Maybe even a flat footer (your plywood!) under the back legs that extends under the blocks.   The blocks will be out of sight and the weight will ballast the back of the fridge and keep it from tipping.  More blocks= more solid.  You want her to be able to hang on to the door when it is open and pull on it some.

Comment: Thank you, Will, THAT is thinking outside the box ;) . 
Hangar bolts are nifty little things indeed. I can take one of the fridge feet to Ace to get the right size and get this done!